# Best way to get NWipe .25

Tags: software-installation

I'm needed the latest version of NWipe as it logs serial numbers of wiped disks and the currently packaged version with 18.04 does not. I'm unsure how to go about doing this and I've not had much luck with Googled suggestions. Any ideas?

Comment: The latest version - 0.25 - is available with Ubuntu 19.04. For 18.04 your only option is compiling: https://github.com/martijnvanbrummelen/nwipe

Comment: So that option only installs .24:  root@pc:/home/user# apt install nwipe
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nwipe
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 nwipe amd64 0.25-1 [32.8 kB]
Fetched 32.8 kB in 1s (53.8 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package nwipe.
Preparing to unpack .../nwipe_0.25-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nwipe (0.25-1) ...
Setting up nwipe (0.25-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
root@pc:/home/user# nwipe -V
nwipe version 0.24
root@pc:/home/user#

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain a USB flash image of ShredOS 2020.02. This is a small linux distribution that boots straight into the **latest master version of nwipe**. Instructions and download link [here](https://github.com/PartialVolume/shredos.2020.02/blob/master/README.md#obtaining-and-writing-shredos-to-a-usb-flash-drive-the-easy-way-). Burn to USB and boot straight into nwipe.

[SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) is a distro that generally keeps up to date with the **latest nwipe releases**. You can download and burn to CD or USB for a bootable nwipe.

I'm also currently working on a Ubuntu PPA to make it easy to keep upto date with the latest release version of nwipe. Details will be published [here](https://github.com/martijnvanbrummelen/nwipe/blob/master/README.md) when completed.

Comment: fun fact I already have a PPA for the backport from Focal which is 0.26 - https://launchpad.net/~teward/+archive/ubuntu/nwipe

Answer (score 0):

Nwipe is now updated to 0.26. Apart from drive serial numbers it also logs system baseboard serial numbers if they were entered into the BIOS by the OEM during manufacture.